# The following has evaluated to null or missing. Android Studio FreeMarker template error

Tags: android, android-studio, wizard

Everytime I try to create a new Activity or Fragment in Android Studio, the wizard sort of crashes. After clicking on Finish, it shows an error code, but doesn't respond to any other clicks and Android Studio has to be killed with the Task Manager. The only way to create a new Activity is using the gallery. [image: Here you can see the wizard with the error code. Trying to close the window would result in another error without the program respoding]

I found bug reports considering this topic and saying it will be fixed in the next update but those reports are quite old now and I've updated to the newest version. Even if you can't tell me, how to fix the entire program, could you tell me how to create a new Fragment, without stumbling into that error again?

**Configuration Version is bellow:**

```
 Android Studio 2.3.3 <br>  Build# AI-162.4069837, built on June 7,
 2017 <br> JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06-amd64
```